# R Markdown Knitting Produces Garbage

Tags: r, geojson, rstudio, ggplot

I don't even know where to begin on describing my problem. I made some maps in R Studio and when I knit the document, it gives me 30 pages of junk.
[image]
I have selected the options to display the output only, and I still get this. I can't turn in my work with 30 pages of junk. What is this stuff and how do I get rid of it?

I'm making my maps with a geojson file of Michigan counties along with some attribute data from other sources. GGPlot is putting everything together.

```
map3 <- ggplot() +
  ggtitle("COVID-19 Case Rates") +
  geom_sf(data = MI_df) +
  geom_sf(data = MI_df, aes(fill = Party, alpha = CaseRate), show.legend = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.justification=c(0.2,0.2), legend.position=c(0.1,0.1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = party_colors)
  scale_color_manual(values = c("DEM" = "#00BFC4",
                                "REP" = "#F8766D"))
  theme_minimal()

map4 <- ggplot() +
  ggtitle("COVID-19 Death Rates") +
  geom_sf(data = MI_df) +
  geom_sf(data = MI_df, aes(fill = Party, alpha = DeathRate), show.legend = TRUE) +
  theme(legend.justification=c(0.2,0.2), legend.position=c(0.1,0.1)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = party_colors)
  scale_color_manual(values = c("DEM" = "#00BFC4",
                                "REP" = "#F8766D"))

  theme_minimal()

grid.arrange(map3, map4, nrow = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up the chunk. You can deactivate the code call with `echo`, `warning` messages and any other kind of `message` (Use also `fig.cap`, `fig.height`, `fig.width` and `fig.align` for plot customization):

````
```{r, echo=F,warning=F, message=FALSE}

# your code

```
````

Comment: Better to use `FALSE` instead of `F` though - `F` can be changed in user code, `FALSE` cant.